# Prometheus exporter for custom scripts (Golang)

Tags: go

This is my first project using Go to study, I've built a simple utility to export output of commands or other scripts in the Prometheus metrics format.

The utility basically get's the output of a command or from a script and stores it into a map, which I'll later use to re-format the output to the Prometheus metric standard output and expose it in a given port.

I feel that I'm not doing the best use of channels to protect it from data races... would very much appreciate any feedback about different approaches or best practices I might have missed.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```golang
// Package go-custom-exporter provides an easy way to export metrics from custom scripts or
// commands to Prometheus without having to worry about doing much code.
//
// The goal is that any routine which can return data in a expected output can be easily
// exported as a Gauge metric with a single command.
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/fsilveir/go-custom-exporter/pkg/utils"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

func main() {
    script, _port, timeout := utils.GetArgs()
    port := fmt.Sprintf(":%v", utils.StringToInteger(_port))

    path := "/metrics"

    // Initialize the first level of the map of strings to store command output
    m := map[int]map[string]string{}

    // Execute command once out of a loop in order to get the required fields
    cmd := exec.Command(script)
    ch := make(chan struct{})

    go updateMap(cmd, ch, m)

    ch <- struct{}{}
    cmd.Start()
    <-ch

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    utils.CheckEmptyMap(m)

    gauge := prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
        prometheus.GaugeOpts{
            Namespace: "prom",
            Subsystem: "custom",
            Name:      "exporter",
            Help:      "Prometheus Gauge Metrics from Custom script/command exporter",
        },
        []string{
            // Name of the metric
            "system",
            "subsystem",
            "metric",
        },
    )
    // Start to serve the data on the target port
    http.Handle(path, promhttp.Handler())
    prometheus.MustRegister(gauge)

    for range m {

        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("INFO: Successfully exposing metrics on port %s", (_port)))

        go func() {
            for {
                i := 0
                go executeCmd(script, m)
                for range m {
                    go updateMap(cmd, ch, m)
                    gauge.With(prometheus.Labels{
                        "system":    m[i]["system"],
                        "subsystem": m[i]["subsystem"],
                        "metric":    m[i]["metric"]}).
                        Set(utils.StringToFloat64(m[i]["value"]))
                    i++
                }
                time.Sleep(utils.StringToSeconds(timeout))
            }
        }()
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(port, nil))
    }

}

// executeCmd will execute a custom scrip or command as a goroutine and return the output to a map
func executeCmd(script string, m map[int]map[string]string) {
    cmd := exec.Command(script)
    ch := make(chan struct{})

    go updateMap(cmd, ch, m)

    ch <- struct{}{}
    cmd.Start()
    <-ch

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    utils.CheckEmptyMap(m)
}

// updateMap will get the values from the custom script or command executed by executeCmd method
// and update a map that will be used to set the values to be exported my main funcion
func updateMap(cmd *exec.Cmd, ch chan struct{}, m map[int]map[string]string) (cmdOutput map[int]map[string]string) {

    defer func() { ch <- struct{}{} }()
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    <-ch

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

    i := 0
    for scanner.Scan() {
        s := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")
        utils.CheckCmdOutput(s)

        // Initialize the second level of the map of strings to store the command output
        m[i] = map[string]string{}
        m[i]["system"] = strings.TrimSpace(s[0])
        m[i]["subsystem"] = strings.TrimSpace(s[1])
        m[i]["metric"] = strings.TrimSpace(s[2])
        m[i]["value"] = strings.TrimSpace(s[3])

        i++
    }
    return m
}
```

Comment: can you share a fully executable example with test data and run commands ?

Comment: Hi @ferada, inside the repository I've included an example shell script and the arguments required to use the utility with it, they can be found at the [following link](https://github.com/fsilveir/go-custom-exporter#setting-up-your-own-scripts). Thanks